# How to set variable equal to a certain substring pattern in bash?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to set a variable equal to a substring from a string that will always start with `cse` and have 3-5 characters afterwards that follows.

For example, if the input string is

```
http://website.com/class/cse111/homework2/test.html
```

I want to extract just

```
cse111
```

from this string.

I have tried

```
coursenum=$(grep -o '[^cse]...')
```

but it's not working. Does anyone know how to handle this?

Thank you,

Comment: Is `cse` part going to be stay the same? Or do you want always want to extract n-th field separated by `/`?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is wrong. `grep -Eo 'cse[^/]{3,5}'` will work.

- `cse` matches the string literally
- `[^/]{3,5}` matches 3 to 5 characters afterwards that are not `/`

If the relevant part is always the 5th field separated by `/` you can use `cut -d/ -f5` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If what you showed us as assignment command is literally what you have in your script, there are two issues.

- First, you have the wrong regular expression for your task. Your expression would look for a string that does *not* start with either `c`,`s`, or `e`, (this is what the `[^cse]` actually does) and is followed by three arbitrary characters (`...`) after this first character, so it would only get four characters in total anyway.
- Second, you are missing the argument to `grep`.

If you are using `bash`, and your source string is stored in a variable `$courseurl`, you can use

```bsh
coursenum="$(grep -o 'cse[^/]\{3,5\}' <<< "$courseurl")"
```

On other shells that don't support "here-strings", use

```bsh
coursenum="$(echo "$courseurl" | grep -o 'cse[^/]\{3,5\}')"
```

Apart from that, the comment by @ArkadiuszDrabcyz and the solution by @Devon point you in the right direction if the course number is always the third component of the course URL.

In general, if you are new to regular expressions, I would recommend looking at tools like the [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) or [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/) that allow you to test regular expressions and see if they do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the 5th `/`-delimited string in the string:

```
$ cut -d '/' -f 5 <<<'http://website.com/class/cse111/homework2/test.html'
cse111
```

If you want the string(s) that starts with `cse` and is terminated by `/`:

```
$ grep -o 'cse[^/]*' <<<'http://website.com/class/cse111/homework2/test.html'
cse111
```

Then use either of these in a command substitution, e.g.

```
num=$( grep -o 'cse[^/]*' <<<'http://website.com/class/cse111/homework2/test.html' )
```

Note that `[^cse]` matches any *single* character that is not a `c`, `s` or `e`, and that `.` matches any single character.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried it but it seems to not work. I typed in 
num=$(grep -o 'cse[^/]*') <<<$2 
(The link is $2) but it does not remove anything :') Thank you for your help though

Comment: @Kim I should have been clearer: `num=$(grep -o 'cse[^/]*' <<<"$2")`

Answer (score 0):

You could also sove this with the use of `sed`

```
coursenum=$(sed 's/^.*\(cse[^/]*\)/.*$/\1/' <<< "${website_url}")
```

or with the use of bash parameter substitution

```
coursenum=cse${website_url#*cse}
coursenum=${coursenum%%\/}
```